# Docker assets not appearing in Playwright tests, but appearing in browser outside of testing

Tags: docker, automated-tests, playwright

Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm very new to web development and Playwright!

I'm attempting to run Playwright tests on a web app that is using Docker.

I have a local repository cloned from GitHub open in VS Code. I've been given a Zip of a Docker image, which I am able to run through Docker Desktop, and the web app is able to display assets / files from the image. I am able to make changes in VS Code that are reflected in the web app while still displaying the assets from Docker.

When I open http://localhost:3001/ through my regular browser, the web app appears, and the example elements (in this case, journal entries) from the Docker image appear correctly on the page.

However, when I run Playwright tests using the same target URL (http://localhost:3001/), these elements from Docker are not present.

I have tried changing the proxy address in webpack.config.js and changing some variables in playwright.config.ts, but reversed most of these when I realised I could be making things worse!

Thank for you any help in advance, much appreciated!